# Who plays the role?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am curious if the following is the correct grammatically?

"кто играет роль Лары?" (Lara's role)

Is there a more common expression tha would fit better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. You may also shorten this like: "*Кто играет Лару?*", or maybe even "*Кто Лара?*", if the context allows to do this without any ambiguity. But these are just colloquial "shortcuts" for the above.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to say:

*Кто исполняет роль Лары?*

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. You can also say "Кто играет Лару / Гамлета / короля?"